# WKWebView show content wrong frame in old project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, wkwebview

I have an old iOS project using Objective C. When I add a WKWebView to a ViewController

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"];

    WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];

    _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:theConfiguration];
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];
    
    self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        
                                             [self.webView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor],
                                             [self.webView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor],
                                             [self.webView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor],
                                             [self.webView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor]
    ]];

    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

If I install app via Xcode with iOS 14, webview works fine, but after I disconnect Xcode and open app directly, webview show content with wrong frame. If I build app in iOS 12.5 via Xcode, web view also show content with wrong frame.
If I create new project from Xcode 12.5, and using same code, it works fine.

This is screenshot when open app via Xcode build

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYb3M.png

And this is screenshot when open app directly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q0uD.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a few days searching, I finally found the cause of the error.
In a UIView Extension file overridden **center** property

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (FrameExtension)

@property CGPoint center;

@end
```

.

```
#import "UIView+FrameExtension.h"

@implementation UIView (FrameExtension)

- (CGPoint)center {
     return CGPointMake(self.frame.origin.x + self.frame.size.width / 2,
                        self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height / 2);
}

- (void)setCenter:(CGPoint)center {
     CGRect frame = self.frame;
     frame.origin = CGPointMake(center.x - self.frame.size.width / 2,
                                center.y - self.frame.size.height / 2);
     self.frame = frame;
}

@end
```

Somehow, when loading the webview, it called **setCenter** which caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

A few observations -

1. This code uses a mix of `_webView` and `self.webView`. For clarity, you should unify the usage for at least this code block.
2. Where exactly are you calling this part? `viewDidLoad()` or After some event? Can you try adding a `layoutIfNeeded()` call after you add this?

```
/// After activating constraints
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

3. You should try to use `leadingAnchor` & `trailingAnchor` instead of `leftAnchor` & `rightAnchor` respectively.

---

If nothing helps, I think your view controller's view storyboard setup isn't updated to use Autolayout. In that case, you can try this -

```
_webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds configuration:theConfiguration];
_webView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
[self.view addSubview:_webView];
```

Please note that in this case - you MUST REMOVE all the constraints related code.

```
/*
self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[ ...... ]];
*/
```

---

Comment: - No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'requiresConstraintBasedLayout'
But if I don't use autolayout, and just use frame, it still same problem.

Comment: For testing, I write this code in viewDidApear, and layoutIfNeeded is not help

Comment: oh sorry, when I used self.view, it show same error.
No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'requiresConstraintBasedLayout'

Comment: Property 'requiresConstraintBasedLayout' not found on object of type 'UIView *'

Comment: webview frame is still true, even scrollview inside and WKWebViewContent frame is still true, but next level subviews is wrong frame

Comment: Does it change anything if you wrap these flexible width/height values in paranthesis? Like `_webView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);`

Comment: it's still the same

Comment: I found problem. See my answer below.